# PHP: Curl is responding slow in loop

Tags: php, curl

I have the following function I am calling in a loop

```
function post( $url, $data ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Accept'             => 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language'    => 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6',
        'Cache-Control'      => 'no-cache',
        'Connection'         => 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type'       => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'DNT'                => '1',
        'Origin'             => 'https://dps.psx.com.pk',
        'Pragma'             => 'no-cache',
        'Referer'            => 'https://dps.psx.com.pk/historical',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest'     => 'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode'     => 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site'     => 'same-origin',
        'User-Agent'         => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With'   => 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'sec-ch-ua'          => '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile'   => '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform' => '"macOS"',
        'Accept-Encoding'    => 'gzip',
    ] );
//  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,
//      'dis-request-id=a349ed4a96a83953fd19740ba4bc2de6; dis-timestamp=2022-03-28T04:00:24-07:00; dis-remote-addr=39.48.180.94' );
    //curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'month=1&year=2022&symbol=OGDC' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );    
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );    
    curl_close( $ch );    
    return $response;
}
```

When I call in loop like below, it takes forever

```
for($x = 0; $x < 200;$x++) {
     $month = 1;
     $year=2022;
     $symbol = "OGDC";
     $data = [];
     $data[] = 'month=' . $month;
     $data[] = 'year=' . $year;
     $data[] = 'symbol=' . strtoupper( $symbol );
     $query = implode( '&', $data );
     $html = post( 'https://dps.psx.com.pk/historical', $query );
}
```

Comment: You're requesting the same data 200 times (sequentially), if one request takes 1 seconds then you should expect 200 requests to take at least 3 minutes.
You could try your requests with something like https://github.com/spatie/fork to run multiple requests concurrently.

Comment: @AndyGee it is taking more than 6 mins and then times out.

Comment: If you run outside of PHP do you get the hang during iteration as well? Is the hang observed on a fixed interval or timing? Does https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php show a non-200 return prior to the hang?

Comment: You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec to process multiple requests.

Comment: @user3783243 not _hang_, it is taking time forever, it works fine if iteration is below 10 or 20 but definitely more records thus more loading time

Comment: @user3783243 I just tried `GuzzleHttp` but no difference. Seems all PHP request libraries are depending on CURL.

Comment: You could use `exec` and run the CURL there.. I don't think that would be much faster but maybe worth trying

Comment: @Volatil3 Accessing the site from here, the load time is 2.149s. doing that 200 times is just over 7 minutes. In order to stop the web server from timing out I recommend outputting some data for each iteration to keep the connection alive. To avoid timeouts all together you could use php on the command line. It could also be the case that the target web server is blocking your requests, so add a delay `sleep(3)` between iterations. The only way to speed up requesting 200, 2 second load time  pages is to parallelize the requests, `exec` can do this or spatie/fork, linked above.

Comment: @AndyGee In actual code I am outputting within loop for sure but it is not printing step by step, rather all in a chunk

Comment: @Volatil3 You will need to output at least 4096 bytes to force the browser to output. `echo '.' . str_pad(' ',4096); flush()`. At least you should see this updating now. However I had a thought about this. Surely caching historical data is the solution as historical data never changes. I'll submit an answer with a basic caching function. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be fetching historical data which is unlikely to change, how about caching that data so it will read from the file system if it's recently been fetched from the remote source.

I've slightly modified your `post` function (first 2 lines) and integrated a new `cachef` function. The configuration will cache the response for 1 week (604800 seconds).

I've also added some output to show progress with `echo '. '.str_repeat(',',4096);` and `flush();` Hope this helps.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 200; $x++) {
  $month = 1;
  $year = 2022;
  $symbol = 'OGDC';
  $data = [];
  $data[] = 'month=' . $month;
  $data[] = 'year=' . $year;
  $data[] = 'symbol=' . strtoupper($symbol);
  $query = implode('&', $data);
  $args = ['https://dps.psx.com.pk/historical', $query];
  $html = cachef('post', $args, 604800);
  echo '. '.str_repeat(',',4096);
  flush();
}




/**
 * Caches the output of any function for a given amount of time
 *
 * @param string function name $func
 * @param array of function arguments $args
 * @param integer number of seconds to cache the function response $seconds 604800 (one week)
 * @param boolean whether to treat the output of the function as JSON $json true
 * @param string relative or path of cached function results (with trailing slash) $cache_dir ./cache
 * @return mixed
 */
function cachef($func, $args, $seconds = 604800, $json = true, $cache_dir = './cache/') {
  // Caches for x seconds ($seconds) the result ($result) of any function ($func) in directory ($cache_dir)
  if (!is_dir($cache_dir)) {
    mkdir($cache_dir, 0755, true);
  }
  $request_hash = md5(json_encode(array($func, $args)));
  $request_file = $cache_dir . $request_hash . '.json';
  $run = false;
  if (file_exists($request_file)) {

    if (filemtime($request_file) < time() - $seconds) {
      $run = true;
    }
  } else {
    $run = true;
  }
  if ($run) {
    $result = $func($args);
    if ($json) {
      file_put_contents($request_file, json_encode($result));
    } else {
      file_put_contents($request_file, $result);
    }
  } else {
    if ($json) {
      $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($request_file), true);
    } else {
      $result = file_get_contents($request_file);
    }
  }
  return ($result);
}

function post($args) {

  $url = $args[0];
  $data = $args[1];

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Accept'             => 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language'    => 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6',
    'Cache-Control'      => 'no-cache',
    'Connection'         => 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type'       => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'DNT'                => '1',
    'Origin'             => 'https://dps.psx.com.pk',
    'Pragma'             => 'no-cache',
    'Referer'            => 'https://dps.psx.com.pk/historical',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest'     => 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode'     => 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site'     => 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent'         => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With'   => 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua'          => '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile'   => '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform' => '"macOS"',
    'Accept-Encoding'    => 'gzip',
  ]);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $response;
}
```